# Trying to get comma delimited list but only get one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT
    gc_category_products.product_id, 
    LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price),price) AS sort_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(category_id, CHAR(8))) AS cats
FROM
    (`gc_category_products`)
JOIN `gc_products` ON `gc_category_products`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
WHERE
        `category_id` = '31'
    OR `category_id` = '35'
    OR `category_id` = '30'
    OR `category_id` = '36'
    OR `category_id` = '37'
    OR `category_id` = '34'
AND 
    `enabled` = 1
GROUP BY
    `product_id`
LIMIT 10
```

And in the `cats` field, it only returns one number, if I take out all the WHERE clauses, it brings back a comma delimited list, but I need those WHEREs to filter my data.

Any ideas?

Sample data

```
gc_category_products
--------------------------
product_id | category_id |
--------------------------
3          | 31          |
3          | 18          |
4          | 35          |
4          | 21          |


gc_products
-----------------------------------
| id | price | saleprice | enabled|
-----------------------------------
| 3  | 23.00 | 0.00      | 1      |
| 4  | 50.00 | 0.00      | 1      |

expected result
--------------------------------
product_id | sort_price | cats |
--------------------------------
| 3        | 23.00      | 31,18|
| 4        | 50.00      | 35,21|
```

Comment: Show some sample data and a desired result.

Comment: If you're getting a comma-delimited list when you take out the `WHERE` clause, that's your answer right there - there IS only one cateogry that doesn't get filtered out

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: The sample data you've given show's what I was talking about - you only have one entry for product 3 (cat 31) and one for product 4 (cat  35) which match the `WHERE` clause.  What are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: @Guido added expected result above

Comment: @sybkar added expected result above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me this sounds like what you want, you want the products that are in *certain* categories, including a list of *all* categories they're in;

```
SELECT
    cat.product_id, 
    LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price),price) AS sort_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(category_id) AS cats
FROM gc_category_products cat
JOIN gc_products p ON cat.product_id = p.id
WHERE cat.product_id IN
  (SELECT product_id 
   FROM gc_category_products gcp 
   WHERE gcp.category_id IN ('31','35','30','36','37','34'))
AND enabled=1
GROUP BY product_id

PRODUCT_ID   SORT_PRICE   CATS
3            23           31,18
4            50           35,21
```

[SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eceb3/8).

Comment: +1 for reading between the lines. I think you most likely have identified the OP's intent..

Answer (score 3):

The `WHERE` clause filters out the additional `category_id`s you expect in your resultset: `'18'` and `'21'`. This query produces the resultset you desire:

```
SELECT
    gc_category_products.product_id, 
    LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price),price) AS sort_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(category_id, CHAR(8))) AS cats
FROM
    (`gc_category_products`)
JOIN `gc_products` ON `gc_category_products`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
WHERE
       `category_id` = '31'
    OR `category_id` = '35'
    OR `category_id` = '30'
    OR `category_id` = '36'
    OR `category_id` = '37'
    OR `category_id` = '34'
    OR `category_id` = '18' /* added */
    OR `category_id` = '21' /* added */
AND 
    `enabled` = 1
GROUP BY
    `product_id`
LIMIT 10
```

A tested example producing the resultset you expect can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71a20/17

---

**However**, please note that there are other potential issues with your query.

1. [The `OR` logical operator has lower precedence than `AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). So your query may not do what you expect.
2. If Joachim [has correctly interpreted your intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14508942/42346) you should modify your `WHERE` clause to include a subquery which performs the filtering. Structuring the query in this way ensures that the additional categories are not filtered from your final resultset.

   WHERE
       `enabled` = 1
   AND EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 
           FROM   `gc_category_products` as `x`
           WHERE  `x`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
                  AND `x`.`category_id` IN 
                      ('31','35','30','36','37','34')
       )

This additional modification is tested to be working to your specifications here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71a20/21/0

Comment: Or maybe: `category_id IN ('30', '31', '34', '35', '36', '37') AND enabled = 1`

Comment: While I agree that brackets are needed for the query to return the _correct_ data, wouldn't you expect _more_ results the way he has it written?

Comment: Both putting brackets around the ORs and changing them to IN provides the same result